# Numpy Hstack dimensions not aligned

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to run a PCA analysis over an dataset representing the 3 bands of an image. The dataset is of size (300000,3) being pixels and 3bands.I find the Eigen values and pairs which are then put into a tuple called `eig_pairs`. I then calculate the variance to determine how many bands to use for PCA.

I determine that I wish to use 2 bands.

My `eig_pairs` shape is a list of tuples of size 3.

Following [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/kkooijman/pca-and-kmeans) I says I need to reshape everything by reducing from original dimension space (3) to how every many a dimension equal to the number of dimensions I wish to use (2). Their example goes for 7 to 4 as shown here:

> ```
> matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(7,1),
>                       eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(7,1),
>                       eig_pairs[2][1].reshape(7,1),
>                       eig_pairs[3][1].reshape(7,1)))
> ```

Following this logic I changed my own to:

> matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0](https://www.kaggle.com/kkooijman/pca-and-kmeans).reshape(3,1),
>                         eig_pairs[1](https://www.kaggle.com/kkooijman/pca-and-kmeans).reshape(3,1)))

However I get the error `ValueError: shapes (3131892,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`

```
#read in image
img = cv2.imread('/Volumes/EXTERNAL/Stitched-Photos-for-Chris/p7_0015_20161005-949am-75m-pass-1.jpg.png',1)
row,col = img.shape[:2]
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

# Pandas dataset
# samples = 3000000, featuress = 3
dataSet = pd.DataFrame({'bBnad':b.flat[:],'gBnad':g.flat[:],'rBnad':r.flat[:]})

print(dataSet.head())
# Standardize the data
X = dataSet.values
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) #converts data from unit8 to float64

#Calculating Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of Covariance matrix
meanVec = np.mean(X_std, axis=0)
covarianceMatx = np.cov(X_std.T)
eigVals, eigVecs = np.linalg.eig(covarianceMatx)

# Create a list of (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples
eig_pairs = [ (np.abs(eigVals[i]),eigVecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eigVals))]
# Sort from high to low
eig_pairs.sort(key = lambda x: x[0], reverse= True)

# Determine how many PC going to choose for new feature subspace via
# the explained variance measure which is calculated from eigen vals
# The explained variance tells us how much information (variance) can 
# be attributed to each of the principal components
tot = sum(eigVals)
var_exp = [(i / tot)*100 for i in sorted(eigVals, reverse=True)]
cum_var_exp = np.cumsum(var_exp)

#convert 3 dimension space to 2 dimensional space therefore getting a 2x3 matrix W
matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(3,1),
                      eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(3,1)))
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: could you provide the image as well? I tried it with an custom image from my pc and it ran with only one warning for StandardScaler

Comment: @Interested_Programmer it seems to be working now although I didn't change anything... Thanks for you're help I guess:)